# Publishing sqlCE(*.sdf) Files with clickonce

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, clickonce, publishing

I am trying to use CLICKONCE deployment to publish my .NET WINFORMS with a Database file (SQLCE - *.sdf) project to my server. I am using C# in my solution.

The problem that I have at this stadium is that my database file is in a different project than my executable files. The project containing the *.sdf is referenced in the Main project. Thus the file is automatically copied to the bin folder of the Main project once it is built but it can not be seen in  (MainProject > Properties > Publish > Application Files) making it impossible for me to publish it to my server.

The problem is thus, that I can't send the *.sdf with the publication of the project.

How do I go to work to fix this problem?

Comment: Move the file to the main project?

Comment: @ErikEJ - that doesn't work if, like me, the "other project" is referenced by two different projects.  For instance, I have one ClickOnce project that is just a small GUI, but needs access to that common DLL with the SqlCe files, and another big application that also needs access to that common DLL and SqlCe file.  That's the whole point of breaking them out into different assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instruction:

1) Create a new Windows Forms application.

2) Add Data Source (select a database file such as SqlDatabase.mdf) to your project.

3) Drag&drop DataGridView1 onto Form1, and using |DataDirectory| path in database connection string.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

'Binding database table to DataGridView

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlDatabase.mdf")

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1", con)

    con.Open()

    Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()

    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "MyTable")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable").DefaultView

    con.Close()

    con = Nothing

End Sub

End Class
```

4) Select SqlDatabase.mdf file in Solution Explorer and look at its properties:

Make sure the "Build Action" property is set as "Content".

The "Copy to Output Directory" property is set as "Copy if newer".

5) Project Property -> Publish tab -> Press "Application Files" Button

Check the database file in list, and make sure its “Publish Status” is set as “Data File (Auto)” and “Download Group” is set as “(Required)”.

6)    Project Property -> Publish tab -> Click “Publish” button to publish your application to generate a Setup.exe file.

Install the Setup.exe file, the database file will be deployed with application in "Data" folder of application Installation folder. An exe.config file will also be deployed along with application in application Installation folder.

[Original source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbinterop/thread/353e10d3-b46e-4234-927d-c2c17d750546)

Comment: The problem at this moment is that I do not have access to the sdf because the database file lies in a different project, that is not the one that is published, within one solution.

If I can get access of it then I will go the above route, until then I am stuck. So I need to get hold of it to choose it in die application files tab under publish.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options available to you. Both involve creating the ClickOnce deployment outside of Visual Studio. Once you want to go beyond the basics you need to move out of Visual Studio.

Option 1) Mage and MageUI - this is a microsoft tool that you can use for putting together ClickOnce deployments. There's a guide here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx

Option 2) ClickOnceMore - this is a tool I wrote to allow you to do more with ClickOnce. You can easily create a project and add files from outside of the main .exe project. There's a getting started guide here: http://clickoncemore.net/documentation/browser.php?page=quick_start_guide.  In your scenario you probably just need to create one file inclusion rule and point it at the bin directory of your app.

Answer (score 0):

1) Select SqlDatabase.sdf file in Solution Explorer and look at its properties:

Make sure the "Build Action" property is set as "Content".

The "Copy to Output Directory" property is set as "Copy if newer".

2) Project Property -> Publish tab -> Press "Application Files" Button

Check the database file in list, and make sure its “Publish Status” is set as “Include” and “Download Group” is set as “(Required)”.

3) Project Property -> Publish tab -> Click “Publish” button to publish your application to generate a Setup.exe file.